# Objective C: Pan gesture only move parent view while all the subviews stay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom UIView that displays some text content.
On top of text content, I have many UIViews look like sticky notes.
The main text content view, which is parent view, can be moved to the left or right side of the screen with pan gesture.
The problem is that sticky note UIViews, which are subviews of the content view, do not move when parent view moves.
When parent view is panned, everything should move together.
How can I do that?

Comment: Putting the code might help

Comment: It can only be that the sticky note views are not children of the view being moved.  Voting to close since there's no code to help with.